# Get data from a "Select" in other fields

Tags: javascript, select, return-value

Someone can help me, I have searched and have not found what I want is that depending on the choice made in other fields take the values ​​of the chosen option eg Value & Name.

UPDATE:
Thanks I tried it by adding the "id" in if it worked, but the Link Name "Not". Modify the script as follows for more definition in both results on my website. Can view this here: [jsfiddle.net/87d5C/2](http://jsfiddle.net/87d5C/2)

Can you help for the name value works?

Html:

```
<select id="Product1">
    <option name="billingcycle=monthly" value="16.00">1 Month</option>
    <option name="billingcycle=semiannually" value="18.00">6 Months</option>
    <option name="billingcycle=annually" value="20.00">12 Months</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li id="price1">16.00</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id="price1"><a href="cart.php?a=add&pid=300&">Order</a></li>
</ul>
```

Script:

```
var select = document.getElementById("Product1"),
    li = document.getElementById("price1"),
    link = li.querySelector("[href='cart.php?a=add&pid=300&']"),
    option;
select.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    li.innerHTML = option.value;
    link.setAttribute("href", "cart.php?a=add&pid=300&"+option.name);
});
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, show us what you tried to do

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve. Could you explain more concisely? use the Edit button to add more information to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (you might want to add an id to your `select` and `ul` elements to make sure you're getting the right one):

```
var select = document.getElementById("Product1"),
    price = document.getElementById("price1"),
    link = document.getElementById("order1").firstChild,
    option;
select.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    price.innerHTML = option.value;
    link.setAttribute("href", "cart.php?a=add&pid=300&"+option.getAttribute("name"));
});
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It just dawned on me that you might have wanted to dynamically create the html in the second code block. I was under the impression it was somewhere in the document already.

Comment: Thanks I tried it by adding the "id" in if it worked, but the Link Name not.

Modify the script as follows for more definition in both results on my website.
Can view this here: http://jsfiddle.net/87d5C/2/

Comment: Setting two elements to the same id is bad practice. All ids should be unique on a document. I recommend changing the second `li` to `order1` rather than `price1` and modify your code accordingly. Would you also mind approving my answer? Please and thank you :)

Comment: Also, you don't need to wrap each individual `li` with a `ul`, just close the first `ul` after the second `li` because that's how lists should look.

Comment: can you help me, this script stay, but I have several products in the same page, if I repeat the script for product fails, does not run well. What do I have to change? for this script to run product by product in the same page

Comment: Please either link me more of your code, or update your question with more of the code to accomodate multiple instances of the products.

Comment: Patrick I see I will explain bad

my code is not in that order, I see that the script changes by class in the text below select.

But it is not, you can see it here. First all select, then prices and last orders http://jsfiddle.net/x5yJa/1/ can you help me little more?

Comment: I apologize but this completely changes the question you initially asked. It seems you're trying to use PHP and jsFiddle doesn't support that syntax. I'm sorry but the intention of this site is not to do your work for you, it's to show you how to do it. If you need a tutorial on JavaScript, I recommend trying https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Getting_Started